# Creating Latitude & Longitude from polygon shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, extract

Could you help me to create long & lat (x and y coordinates in degrees) for polygon shapefile?

When I used directly QGIS export vectors to csv file, it didn't work.

Here is the example file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lfkwMQADzsiMKCZsOeuFqQAHGUE9Qni8?usp=sharing

Comment: You missed the shp file in your drive shared folder. Otherwise looking at prj file it looks your shapefile is in system using lat long and so when exporting correct shp to csv it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi miro, l already put shp files in folder. still can't get long lat after export it to csv

Comment: I can't see it there, there are 5 files but not *.shp, which holds the geometry. Apart of dbf, shx, prj (qpj, cpg) you need to have shp file.

Comment: sorry I wasn't refresh mydrive. please take a look again. Thank you
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13fW6u4CkkRpP4ChaUb5UoK60d0PmvKpP?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, that works, thank you. Now, you have polygons shapefile. So what coordinates do you want to export into csv? Centroids for these polygons? I see in table you have columns lat and long which are empty. Dou you want to fill these with centroids coordinates and then epxort to csv?

Comment: i don't have polygon shapefile. I need this long & lat so I can make 2 maps in tableau using dual axis. Because in this shp file long & lat doesn't exist, I can not make the map I want.

Comment: The shapefile you shared in your drive is polygon layer. It has 12 multipolygons - Indonesia split into these 12 parts. If you want long and lat for these polygons, you need to calculate it as e.g. coordinates of centroids of these polygons. But I do not think you do. I think you have wrong shapefile, and you wanted to have point shapefile instead.

Comment: the shapefile contains 12 parts/regions. I need long lat for each region. is it possible to do that

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer for that.

Comment: I'll be waiting. thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you have polygon shapefile, you need to first extract lat and long coordinates for the polygons. This is typically done as coordinates of centroids. But you can also extract minimum, maximum etc.

Your shapefile also must be in some coordinate system which uses degrees (lat, long) - if it is not, you need to first reproject it (Vector / Data management tools / Reproject Layer...).

1. Select layer in layer list and **Open Field Calculator** (abacus icon in top menu). Or Right click on layer / Open attribute Table to see all columns and click on abacus icon in top menu of table window.
2. Select if you want to create new field or update existing (if you use existing field make sure the field type is number type with enough decimals)
3. As **expression** write for long: **x(centroid($geometry))**, for lat **y(centroid($geometry))**

Once you have both lat and long fields filled in you can export the layer (or better say attribute table) into csv.

Comment: miro, thank you for your help. I can extract long and lat in my shapefile.

Comment: if I want long lat create polygon, what should I replace 'centroid' with?
when I use long lat derived from that calculation, only dots appear in map.
* using geometry
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mI0-xDfGE5_AOomjdyUz1Npy-PvToGBq/view?usp=sharing

* using long lat
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ra0qoQQf5S-MhiFDbz76sYXT8tzMGGsC/view?usp=sharing

* other map/data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vY_5miniat0zDUJTNw_DzpiFTEw1UWJL/view?usp=sharing

if I join this 2 maps, the result like this 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10G384ikYkT5Abshl28i2qE7-OeqrahYl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @billydamanik sorry but I do not follow. If you want to view polygons with lat long of centroids in tableau just import the updated shapefile you created with extracted lat long into tableau. You need to zip shapefile (all sub files) to be able to import it into tableau.

Comment: miro, already solved in tableau. thank you